# Abstract Structure - Can't Really change it

Tags: formatting, abstract

I'm using the structure of Latex as taken from [this site](https://www.aanda.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=129&Itemid=173)
The problem is that the Abstract format is like this

```
\abstract
  % context heading (optional)
  % {} leave it empty if necessary  
   {


   To investigate the physical nature of the `nuc\-leated instability' of
   proto giant planets, the stability of layers
   in static, radiative gas spheres is analysed on the basis of Baker's
   standard one-zone model.}
  % aims heading (mandatory)
   {It is shown that stability
   depends only upon the equations of state, the opacities and the local
   thermodynamic state in the layer. Stability and instability can
   therefore be expressed in the form of stability equations of state
   which are universal for a given composition.}
  % methods heading (mandatory)
   {}
```

And the result is pretty much ugly and not needed for my purpose. It splits the Abstract like [image: this]

Heading:

Aims:

etc.

but what I want is just a plain text, no subtitles, but most of them are mandatories and don't know how to change them

Comment: your question is very unclear. the markup that you show for abstracts is not the usual latex markup. If you are using a class required for journal submission, then the style of the abstract is not the choice of the author, the whole point of such a class is to remove choice from the author and enforce the journal style. If you are not submitting to that journal, do not use that class.

Comment: But  I want a Paper-Like Format and that was the only one I could find. It's two listed and all and excluding this strange Abstract format, everything else is fine

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I uploaded the photo to see what I mean.

Comment: I can not guess what you mean by "a paper like format" (and I doubt any other reader can) but it makes absolutely no sense to use a class that is designed to remove all choice and enforce the style of one particular publication if you are not using that publication. Just use `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I mean Author, Institute, dates, Abstract (not like this one tho) and all those hard to make yourself things.

Comment: I can only recommend that you start with `article` (or a larger generic class such as `memoir` or koma `scrartcl`) and if you have a problem with some specific formatting ask a question with a complete reproducible test document and ask how to fix the specific issue.

Comment: @user174411 *that was the only one I could find* -- there's quite a number here: https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals Take your pick. As David said, templates aren't designed to be changed. So if it does not suit your style (assuming this isn't for journal submission), just choose another one, or write one yourself.

Comment: @Troy Ow! Much appreciated dude. That helped a lot. Would Upvote if it was answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly an answer, just some tough advice.

*that was the only one I could find* -- there's quite a number of journal templates here: sharelatex.com/templates/journals

Take your pick. As David said, templates aren't designed to be changed. So if it does not suit your style (assuming this isn't for journal submission), just choose another one, or write one yourself.